# I need to serialize json file which includes xml inside

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, asp.net-core

I have JSON and I need to deserialize it.Json file includes XML inside. Any suggestions?

```
{"nt":0,"r":true,"o":[{"test":"20fgfgdfgdfAZ20AIgdg151","fddf":"ZregrIPgdffgfSgfg","d":"<DataPDU xmlns="urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0">
<Body>
</AppHdr>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:">  
      ..... 
    </Document></Body>
</DataPDU>"}]}
```

Comment: The xml is all basically a string. Have you tried first deserializing the Json and then as a second step the XML separately?

Comment: I've tried to deserialize to an object, but it throws an exception

Comment: It would help to also show us what you have tried and what is the exact error, to be able to provide better answers :)

Comment: I've tried to create a model to deserialize JSON. But this XML file structure would not be the same, every time XML structure is changing. This is my problem)

Comment: When I try to create object using online converters as JSON2C# it says Invalid JSON syntax

Comment: Check this: `"<DataPDU xmlns="urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0">`. How are you generating this json? Because it is invalid. The special characters in the XML content must be escaped.

Comment: How can I escape these special characters?

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though your JSON string is invalid. You have quotation marks unescaped in the `o[0].d`, or the XML section. I have provided a version of the JSON with the escaped quotation marks below.

```
{
    "nt": 0,
    "r": true,
    "o": [
         {
            "test": "20fgfgdfgdfAZ20AIgdg151",
            "fddf": "ZregrIPgdffgfSgfg",
            "d": "<DataPDU xmlns=\"urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0\"><Body></<Document xmlns=\"urn:iso:\">  ..... </Document></Body></DataPDU>"
         }
     ]
}
```

Using .NET Core 3.1 and the `System.Text.Json` namespace you can deserialize the above json using something along the lines:

```
async Task Main()
{
    string fileName = "ExampleJson.txt";
    Example example = null;

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        example = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Example>(fs);
    }
}
```

Documentation on using the `System.Text.Json` namespace can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).

Answer (score 0):

> Note that `"` has to change to `\"` in your xml-**STRING**, understood that code won't work . ;)

```
using System.Text.Json;
public myJson()
{
    string json = "<json>";
    Rootobject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
}
public class Rootobject
{
    public int nt { get; set; }
    public bool r { get; set; }
    public O[] o { get; set; }
}

public class O
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public string fddf { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can not change " to \" using string.Replace() method.Can you suggest something?

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do this, but when there would be a whitepace more or less it won't run propperly. Is there no way to replace those "